# Philosophy of scroll bars

Tags: user-interface, interface, editor, usability

Suppose I want to design my own text editor . simply like notepad. Without using any richtextbox or other controls LIKE **EDIT** in C++. Main Handle is just a window in C++ or usercontrol in C#. The Question is here for scrolling option , how can I perform scrolling when user is typing. I mean vertical scrolling here . What is Philosophy of works of scroll bars in **C++ windows** or **C# user controls** ?

Should I Clear the **(Usercontrol or Window)** When User reaches to end of **(Usercontrol or Window)** and then Put caret on start of **(Usercontrol or Window)** ? What about scrolling with thumb or hand scrolling ? How can I find the Text Position which scroll to ?

Comment: Are you designing for mouse&keyboard or touch?  It turns out that the affordances needed for each are different (for example, scroll bars are useless on touch because there's not enough real-estate to select the thumb)

Comment: One other question: what does this question have to do with c++ or visual-c++ (or Java and C# for that matter)?

Comment: opps , I  will design it for mouse & keyboard . and scroll bar is commercial control for java and C++ or C# . i have used C++ win32 programming before . I woild like that other programmers like java and C++; see this topic .

Comment: Shouldn't this question be shifted to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nav: [Nope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004657/philosophy-of-scroll-bars)

Answer (score 1):

> What is Philosophy of works of scroll bars ...

In short: Do what is least surprising. In your case this means copy whatever scrolling behaviour your users are already familiar with.