# Philosophy of scroll bars

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Philosophy of  scroll bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000591/philosophy-of-scroll-bars)

Please suppose I want to design my own text editor . simply like notepad.
Without using any **richtextbox** or other controls LIKE **EDIT** in C++.
Main Handle is just a window in C++ or usercontrol in C#.
The Question is here for scrolling option , how can I perform scrolling when user
is typing.
I mean vertical scrolling here . What is Philosophy of works of scroll bars in C++ windows or
C# user controls ?

Should I Clear the **(Usercontrol or Window)** When User reaches to end of **(Usercontrol or Window)** and then Put caret on start of **(Usercontrol or Window)** ?

What about scrolling with thumb or hand scrolling ? How can I find the Text Position which scroll to ?

Comment: This should really be on http://anthropomorphism.widget.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry, but this is an exact duplicate of [Philosophy of  scroll bars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000591/philosophy-of-scroll-bars)

Comment: opening notepad/word/VisualStudio and see what happen isn't a solution ?

Comment: Eli Bendersky , The Both authors are me . ever stackoverflow or this website .

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this I take a similar attitude to language. Consider your audience and common usage patterns - that will steer you in the right direction. It may not give you a philosophy, but you will be able to make decisions which is most important.

So, look at other text editors and determine what users are comfortable with and what users will expect. Using Microsoft Word or Visual Studio as a guide is going to be a pretty safe bet. Deviating from standard practice is more risky; if you want to try something radical, make sure you get other people to try it and confirm your innovation.

One concrete piece of advice: Don't do anything like Google Wave's scrollbars! :P